# Issue with bootstrap modal usage

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

Not getting my bootstrap modals to pop up. I know it is something simple, just not putting my finger on it. My code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="criteria" style="font-size: 14px;">Criteria:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="criteria" ng-model="criteria" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. more than 80%)">
    </div>

<!-- criteriaModal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="criteriaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="criteriaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean consequat odio vel fermentum faucibus. Phasellus vestibulum, justo sed vestibulum bibendum, risus mauris congue nisi, et iaculis ipsum nisl a turpis. Vivamus et purus diam. Proin sagittis nisl eu porttitor posuere. Phasellus feugiat nec elit et hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit a quam eget malesuada. Cras lobortis augue nibh, a feugiat justo consequat ac. In sit amet pulvinar massa. In maximus, justo eget elementum laoreet, lacus nunc molestie lectus, at congue neque nisl quis est. Nam non laoreet mauris. Phasellus non ullamcorper libero. Duis dapibus ornare arcu in fringilla. Curabitur molestie ex eu nunc ultricies, id pharetra nisl semper.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" data-dismiss="modal" value="okay">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: What does _Not getting my bootstrap modals to pop up_ mean? They aren't working at all or not working how you want them to work? If they aren't at all check your console for errors and make sure **jQuery** and **BootstrapJS** are in use.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Open Bootstrap Modal With Jquery on (#criteria Button ) Click

```
$("#criteria").click(function(e){

$("#criteriaModal").modal("show")
```

})

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="criteria" style="font-size: 14px;">Criteria:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="criteria" ng-model="criteria" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. more than 80%)">
    </div>

<!-- criteriaModal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="criteriaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="criteriaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean consequat odio vel fermentum faucibus. Phasellus vestibulum, justo sed vestibulum bibendum, risus mauris congue nisi, et iaculis ipsum nisl a turpis. Vivamus et purus diam. Proin sagittis nisl eu porttitor posuere. Phasellus feugiat nec elit et hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit a quam eget malesuada. Cras lobortis augue nibh, a feugiat justo consequat ac. In sit amet pulvinar massa. In maximus, justo eget elementum laoreet, lacus nunc molestie lectus, at congue neque nisl quis est. Nam non laoreet mauris. Phasellus non ullamcorper libero. Duis dapibus ornare arcu in fringilla. Curabitur molestie ex eu nunc ultricies, id pharetra nisl semper.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" data-dismiss="modal" value="okay">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It will work for you.
May be u library inclusion is not proper

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code. it looks OK and tested it on JSfiddle (it works). seems like you didn't include bootstrap's js or Jquery lib. So please make sure you include all required libraries in right sequence. either you can use following code or you can download files then include them.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

https://jquery.com/download/

Moreover you don't need you bind click function to open modal box. because you already have code. so it will call modal box and open it.  `<a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal">
<span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign">
</span></a></label>`

**GOOD LUCK**